# Python POST works only if I GET CSRF token before I POST, why?

Tags: python, http, post, http-post

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()
    result = session_requests.get(login_url)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    veri_token = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/input[1]/@value")[0]
    print(veri_token)

    headerpayload = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Host': host,
        'Origin': origin,
        'Referer': login_url,
        '__RequestVerificationToken': veri_token
    }

    payload = {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": veri_token,
        "Q_b9849eb2-813d-4d0a-a1ce-643f1c8af986_0": "name",
        "Q_62ebd8c8-7d45-481d-a8b1-ad54a390a029_0": "name@utoronto.ca",
        "FormId": "276caa59-80a5-4ced-9b9d-025e1d753b4a",
        "_ACTION": "Continue",
        "PageIndex": "1"
    }

    result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headerpayload
    )

    print(result.status_code)
```

If I run this code everything works fine. But if I make the script print out the token and then just specify the token rather than get it before sending the post, it fails with a CSRF error. Any idea why?
EDIT: Just to clarify, I have to run both the get request and post together for this to work, if I separate them into two scripts and manually enter the veri_token it fails.

Comment: The csrf token is a security mechanism to secure you fron man in the middle (mitm) attacks. Without it, someone could catch requests you send to a server modify them and forward it or send you a fake response. The idea of a csrf token is to ensure that the sender of the POST request (with the csrf token) is the same as the one who requested the csrf token to disallow mitm attacks. When you request the token and send it from another file, you do exactly what the token tries to prohibit. That's the reason it's only working when requesting the token and sending post request in one process.

Comment: @schilli thanks for the clarification. Makes sense now. Wish you the best.